# How to extract audio/video file duration?

Tags: c++, c, video, audio, duration

I need to find the duration of numerous formats of audio and video files, in milliseconds. I've been searching around for a while, but I can't find anything that will let me do this. I'm using C/++ in Linux. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/) SourceFourge project that shows this info. You can look in its code for that.